# Android permission WRITE_APN_SETTINGS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to make an app that, if I'm on android< ICS writes some APN settings, otherwise does something else. The problem is that, when i write in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"/>
```

the manifest returns me an error, because the permission to write apn settings is only available with sdk<14

What can I do to use the permission on android versions where this permission is allowed mantaining the compatibility with sdk>14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your app with `target-sdk` set to lowest supported version, which in your case should be pre v14

Comment: Would love to see an alternative solution